Postgresql Get Json[] to Object List Net7
I'm trying to read/write Json[] from a Postgresql database.
The write part works well, but the read doesn't
The table looks like this:

To write into Database i use this code
  public async Task Update(string email, string deviceId, 
  IEnumerable<TrendLine>trendLines)
  {
     using var connection = this.Context.CreateConnection();
     var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(trendLines);
     var sql = $"UPDATE \"{email}\" SET ChartLines = array['{json}']::json[] WHERE 
     deviceId = '{deviceId}'";
     await connection.ExecuteAsync(sql);
  }

The Class TrendLine
 public class TrendLine
 {
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int Minimal { get; set; }
  public int Maximal { get; set; }
  public string Unit { get; set; }

  public TrendLine(string name, int minimal, int maximal, string unit)
  {
     this.Name = name;
     this.Minimal = minimal;
     this.Maximal = maximal;
     this.Unit = unit;    
  }
  public TrendLine()
  {
     
  }
}

read code
  public async Task<IEnumerable<TrendLine>> GetTrendLines(string ?email, string ? 
  deviceId)
  {
   using var connection = this.Context.CreateConnection();
   var sql = $"SELECT ChartLines FROM \"{email}\" WHERE deviceId = '{deviceId}'";
   return await connection.QueryAsync<TrendLine>(sql);
  }

the read method returns only one Entry but this is null
the goal is to get all array entrys and convert it in IEnummerable
can explane someone how that works
thanks
Markus

The code is wide open to SQL injection attacks and syntax errors simply because email addresses aren't valid table names. Check the NpgSQL JSON docs to see how to query and modify JSON values. It's a lot easier than this
